# Calculate the autocorrelation of a time series created from a normal distribution

Tags: matlab, octave, autocorrelation

I generate a time series from a normal distribution and then I try to plot the autocorrelation by using the following code snippet:

```matlab
ts1 = normrnd(0,0.25,1,100);
autocorrelation_ts1 = xcorr(ts1);
```

I was expecting that the autocorrelation would show 1 for x=0 and almost 0 for the rest of values, instead I get value 6 at axis position 100.

I think the question applies both to Matlab and Octave but I am not sure.

[image: autocorrelation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that your second line of code is wrong. I think you meant to put

```
autocorrelation_ts1 = xcorr(ts1);
```

Other than this, I think your solution is correct. The reason the max value is at 100 and not 0 is because a temporal shift of 0 in the autocorrelation actually happens on the 100th iteration of the correlation function. In other words, the numbers on the X axis don't correspond to time.

To get time on the X axis change your code to

```
[autocorrelation_ts1, shifts] = xcorr(ts1);
```

Then

```
plot(shifts, autocorrelation_ts1)
```

With regard to the max value, [matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xcorr.html#mw_75d75f40-f9d0-4598-a385-71f0f2fd9134) for `xcorr` indicates that 1 is not the maximum output value of the function when called without the normalization argument. If you want to normalize such that all values are 1 or less, use

```
[autocorrelation_ts1, shifts] = xcorr(ts1, 'normalized');
```

Comment: The second line was a copy&paste typo. I have tried using the shifts and now the autocorrelation is centered around zero as you state. It seems that Octave's `xcorr` lacks 'normalized' parameter, although as you point it is the way to solve it in Matlab

Comment: Manual normalization might work in octave. Before plotting: `autocorrelation_ts1 = autocorrelation_ts1./max(autocorrelation_ts1);`

Comment: That works. Now I am wondering why autocorrelation seems to be statistically lower for larger lags/shifts. I would expect being 1 at 0 and equally small in the rest of shifts

Comment: Not the case on my end. Maybe try clearing your variables and running the code over again from scratch. Could just be the particular random time series that you ended up with.

Answer (score 0):

Just as complementary reference to Scott's answer, this is the complete code snippet, including stem chart scaling to show up to 20 shifts/lags.

```matlab
[auto_ts1, lags] = xcorr(ts1);
ts_begin = ceil(size(lags,2)/2);
ts_end = ts_begin + 20;
stem(lags(ts_begin:ts_end),auto_ts1(ts_begin:ts_end)/max(auto_ts1), 'linewidth', 4.0, 'filled')
```